# How to change an iOS project to not use the nib at all and just work with Objective-C code?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xib, nib

After we create a Single View App on Xcode 4.3.2, are there a couple of things we can do to make the project not use the `.nib` (the `.xib`) at all?

Right now we can click on the `.xib` and change its custom class in Xcode to our FooView class, and do the initialization in `initWithCoder` instead of `initWithFrame`, and the `.xib` is still being used, but almost not modified.

Can we change a couple of things to make the `.xib` not used at all, and that the code will use `initWithFrame`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's certainly possible, but not a good idea.

Comment: why not?  because I am actually quite used to laying out all the UI widgets by Objective-C code, in a Cocoa Touch app or in a Cocos2d app

Comment: The general idea is that it is better to rely on configuration instead of code if possible. Read up on dependency injection.

Comment: that is for, if the app is to work on iPhone, then one `.xib` handles it (at runtime), and if running on iPad, then another `.xib` handles it, so the Objective-C code won't be a mess?  (and our product manager, program manager, or UI/graphics designer can also edit the `.xib` files without touching Objective-C code...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Create a Single View Application
-Delete the .xib file that was automatically created
-Open the view controller that was automatically created and override the `-loadView` method:

```
-(void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease]; //If using ARC you must remove autorelease
}
```

Comment: it compiles and run except it doesn't use `FooView.h` and `.m` at all?

Comment: Oh, you have a separate view... then init self.view with your view:
`self.view = [[FooView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];`

Comment: oh don't we always have a separate view?  I always have one so that I will implement the `drawRect` of that class

Comment: Not always it depends on the case. For example if I want to create a view controller that has a view, whose view hierarchy contains only standart UIKit controls (labels, textfields, buttons...) I actually don't need to override the `drawRect:` method and therefore I just create a blank view as I have shown in the example in my answer. Otherwise as in your case you have a custom view and initialize it. The important thing here is the overriding the `-loadView` method that supplies the `self.view` with the root view...